# Symfony2 get roles from the login response

Tags: symfony, response, roles, hwioauthbundle

In my `Symfony2` project i'm using `HwiOAuthbundle` to login users with `Salesforce` users, and in my `user provider` i get the information  about the user: `email, nickname, password`,... etc. And i wanna know if how can i get the `role` of the authenticated user directly from the `response`.
this my user provider code :

```
class UserProvider extends OAuthUserProvider {
    public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
        {
            $username = $response->getUsername(); 
            $email = $response->getEmail();
            $nickname = $response->getNickname();
            $realname = $response->getRealName();


        //set data in session
        $this->session->set('email', $email);
        $this->session->set('nickname', $nickname);
        $this->session->set('realname', $realname);

        $result = $this->doctrine->getManager()->getRepository('EnvivioUserBundle:User')->findOneBy(array(
                'username' => $username,
        ));
        if (!count($result)) {
            $user = new User();
            $user->setUsername($username);
            $user->setRealname($realname);
            $user->setNickname($nickname);
            $user->setEmail($email);                        
            //Set some wild random pass since its irrelevant, this is Google login
            $factory = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory');
            $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
            $password = $encoder->encodePassword(md5(uniqid()), $user->getSalt());
            $user->setPassword($password);  
            $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
        } else {
            $user = $result; /* return User */
        }

        //set id
        $this->session->set('id', $user->getId());  
        return $this->loadUserByUsername($response->getUsername());
    }
```

id don't know if i can get the roles frol `$response` like `$response->getRoles()`

Comment: when i use `$roles = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getRoles()` i get this : `roles= array(0) { }`

Answer (score 0):

usually it works as:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
$this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

so after you get username from a response, you get/create new user then you get get his roles as $user->getRoles();

do you have at security.yml  imilar as

```
security:
    providers:
        main:
            entity: { class: MyApp\UserBundle\Entity\User, property: username }
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
```

if you use it with FosUserBundle

**UPDATE:** 
I was little bit confused about "roles", and seems you are mixing notion "role" from symfony and "role" from external site. Unfortunately it won't work "from the box".

First you can look at UserResponseInterface https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/OAuth/Response/UserResponseInterface.php and see that there is no any field associated with roles.

So I suppose you need make own custom solution by looking to "Salesforce" api and check is it possible to pass user role. Then if it is possible to pass you will need to extend Hwi to get passed roles from response

Comment: i'm not using `FosUserBundle`, and what i wanna do is to set for the authenticated user the same role he has in `Salesforce`, and i'm wondering if i can i get the role directly from the response so i can register it directly in my Database